# Android NDK - Can not debug in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, xamarin, android-ndk

I have today installed Visual Studio 2017 (And re-installed…) and trying to debug an Android app in C++.
When I starting the app in debug mode in a Microsoft Android Emulator I get a error message box:

> Could not locate the Android Debug Bridge (adb.exe)

And emulator is starting anyway.. and now I trying to start the app again and I get this error message in the Output:

> 1>Error installing the package. The device '' is invalid or not
>   running.  Please switch to another device, or use the Android Virtual
>   Device (AVD) Manager to start a compatible emulator, or connect a
>   compatible Android device.
>
> 1>The device is invalid or is not running.

Notice the empty device name.

When I start the app in a real Android Device I get this error message box:

> Unable to start debugging. Android command 'run-as' failed. Packable
>   'com.**********************' is unknown.
>
> Troubleshooting steps:
>   - Try launching the app from the app list. If the app is not in the app list, or cannot be started, this may indicate a problem with the
>   app deployment.
>   - Make sure that you have installed all updates available for your device.
>   - Install the latest firmware or flash the device using the latest available image. This can be helpful even if you are already on a
>   latest version of Android as the over-the-air Android upgrade process
>   may corrupt file permissions needed for native debugging. For many
>   Samsung devices, this can be done using Kies.
>   - Report the problem to your manufacturer. The Android Compatibility Test Suite 'testRunAsHasCorrectCapabilities' tests for this condition
>   and is likely failing.

But my app is installing in the Android device and can be started.

I feel Android developing in Visual Studio is buggy. I have using Xamarin Android with C# and it often works well.

Any ideas? Someone how has get same errors?

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because debugging native code in your app requires running gdbserver – a special tool that runs on the Android device and exposes the internals of your app to the debugger. If your Android device has too restrictive rights on the /data/system/packages.list file, the run-as tool won’t be able to read the file and launch gdbserver with the correct permissions. VisualGDB provides a workaround that allows launching the gdbserver directly from your app and connecting to it automatically. Open VisualGDB Project Properties, go to the Debug Settings page and select “Start gdbserver – manually from the app”

For more information you can refer to [here](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/run-as/)

Comment: Hm okey, so the problem is that the Android Device do not allow me to debug  from visual studio. I will test the VisualGDB and se if I can debug it. But what about the Microsoft Android Emulator, Shoulnt it works out of the box?